# Navigating between fragments in sap fiori

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am working on a sap fiori app, & i have a problem navigating from one fragment to the other. I checked the documentation but it doesn't specify how.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not possible to navigate to a fragment in routing because the loaded object will be instantiated with sap.ui.view which expects the given parameter to be a view instead of  a fragment. The fragment can be first instantiated and shown earliest in the ‘routeMatched’ handler.

There is documentation on using fragments.
[“Reusing UI parts: Fragments”.](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.30.7/docs/guide/36a5b130076e4b4aac2c27eebf324909.html)

Comment: if it's not possible to navigate, from a fragment to another, i can't create a return button to return to the detail view for example ?

Comment: I assume that you have a view with a fragment as dialog.  The fragment is opened with sap.m.Dialog.open() in the controller to which the dialog is attached.

Then on sap.m.Dialog.close() you have an event which triggers a method in the view controller.  From there you can trigger the navigation as required.